# Aligning the <UL> Of A Navigation Bar

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, html

This is how the navigation bar of a website I'm currently working on appears i.e to the left:

[image]

I would however like to shift the navigation bar to the right of the screen such that 'Editorial' is against the right border of the screen. What changes would I have to make to the following CSS/HTML code of the same?

**CSS Code Of Navigation Bar**

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #FF0346;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #FF0346;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #FF0346
}
.navbar-inverse {
  background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-image: none;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #A6A6A6
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #0D0D0D
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #333333
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-top-color: #999999
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #999999
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header" float>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src='dummylogo.png' width="100" height="100" alt="HEG Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
    
        <li>
          <a href="gameprojects.php">Game Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li  >
          <a href="hardware.php">Hardware</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="wvm.php">Written & Visual</a>
        </li>
<li class="active">
          <a href="twitchcorner.php">Twitch Corner</a>
        </li>
<li>
          <a href="Community.php">Community</a>
        </li>
<li>
        <a href="editorial.php">Editorial</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Apologies. corrected that!

Answer (score 4):

Simply float your navbar-nav class to the right.

Html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">...</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
   float: right;
}
```

It looks like you are using Bootstrap from the class names. As pointed out in the comments by sourRaspberri you should clear the float. Bootstrap has a clearfix included. After the closing `</ul>` add this HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies, the HTML code I attached was incorrect. The correct one has now been put up and you will notice that the UL already has a class declared. Is it possible to float it to the right, and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Good addition @sourRaspberri - i've updated the answer with that advice.

Comment: Updated the answer @SeanBragança . You can add a float to any CSS class declaration.

Comment: Thanks @JonKyte! Though why should I be clearing really?

Comment: You may run into problems down the line with floated and non-floated elements overlapping is all. You don't *have* to clear, it's not a hard rule, but 99% of the time it will give the result you want as opposed to not clearing floats. @SeanBragança